# Rails ActiveRecord Refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mixins

I've created ActiveRecord classes for every type of model in [OpenAir](http://www.openair.com/) and the synchronization code has been re-factored to the below self.run_etl.  I would like to go one more step to convert

```
class OACategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :oa_cost_center, foreign_key: :cost_centerid

  def to_s
    name
  end

  def self.run_etl(logger=nil)
    open_air_type = 'Category'
    OAETL.etl(logger, OACategory.table_name, open_air_type) do |xml_node|
      OATransform.transform_attributes(OACategory, xml_node)
    end
  end
end
```

Into

```
class OACategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :oa_cost_center, foreign_key: :cost_centerid
  syncs_with_openair 'Category'

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Please advise.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use ActiveSuppurt::Concerns

```
module OASync
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    cattr_accessor :oa_syncs_with
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def syncs_with_openair(syncs_with)
      self.oa_syncs_with = syncs_with
    end

    def run_etl(logger=nil)
      open_air_type = self.oa_syncs_with
      OAETL.etl(logger, self.table_name, open_air_type) do |xml_node|
        OATransform.transform_attributes(self, xml_node)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And then in my class

```
class OACategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  include OASync
  syncs_with_openair 'Category'

  belongs_to :oa_cost_center, foreign_key: :cost_centerid

  def to_s
    name
  end

end
```